# Access to left and right projection settings in vr mode

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, webvr, react-360

I'm checking web-vr frameworks and looking for an availability to change the projection settings/the camera settings for left and right eye. Is it somehow possible or this is done automatically by the browser?

I checked A-Frame framework from mozilla and react-vr but I could not find such options.

Answer (score 0):

The camera projections are provided by the browser through [the WebVR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VRDisplay/getFrameData) and are specific to each headset. It's probably something you don't want to change.